# Acesso ao API na porta 443 retornando Connection timed out

Tags: php, json, ssl, openssl

Estou configurando um webAPI e após configurar tudo (id, key, signature, demais dados que o api pede) e autenticar pelo HEADER no php utilizando json e CURL para postar no site o retorno está sendo `Curl error: Failed to connect to 111.222.333.444 port 443: Connection timed out` . Meu código:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

//DADOS DE ACESSO
$id = "xxx";
$retailerName = "xxx";

$key = "xxx";

//PRODUTO
//vars of product:fictional data
$upc = "799366289999";
$amount = "20.00";

//URL DE ACESSO
$function = "requestActivateCode";

//usado pra criar a canonical
$resPath = "/v1/activateCode";

$url = "https://111.222.333.444/v1/";

$urlCall = $url.$function;

//HTTP HEADERS
$date = gmdate("M, d Y H:i:s \G\M\T", time());
$contentType = "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8";
$accept = "Accept: application/json";
$xIncommDateTime = substr(substr_replace(date('c'), substr(round(microtime(), 3), 1, 8), 19, 0), 0, -6) . "Z";

//authorization
$type = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
$canonical = ($xIncommDateTime) + ($type) + ($resPath);

$signature = hash_hmac ('sha1', $key, $canonical);
$idEncoded = base64_encode($id);
$signatureEncoded = base64_encode($signature);
$authorization = "Incomm ". $idEncoded .':'. $signatureEncoded;

$header = array("Date: ".$date, $contentType, $accept, "X-Incomm-DateTime: ".$xIncommDateTime, "Authorization: ".$authorization);


//PARAMS example
$params = array("RetailTransactionRequest" =>
    array(
        "code" => "0000002381237220",
        "amount" => $amount,
        "upc" => $upc,
        "transactionID" => "1234",
        "dateTime" => $xIncommDateTime,
        "retailerName" => $retailerName
    )
);

$request = json_encode($params);


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlCall);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);  
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 443);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
echo curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true); // enable tracking
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;

$headerSent = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT ); // request headers

echo "<pre>";
print_r($headerSent);
echo "</pre>";

if($result === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
    echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

E sempre me retorna : `Curl error: Failed to connect to 111.222.333.444 port 443: Connection timed out` , oque posso fazer para acessar corretamente ??? obrigado

Comment: UP: em servidor de produção o erro está diferente

`Not Found
The server has not found anything matching the request URI
You can get technical details here.
Please continue your visit at our home page.`

Comment: `111.222.333.444` é um IP ou um nome? Acredito que você o tenha ocultado por motivos de segurança, mas por favor seja mais claro. No servidor de testes, o HTTPS esta devidamente configurado? Se executar `netstat -l` a porta 443 aparece como `listening`? No servidor de produção, o comando `ping 111.222.333.444` consegue encontrar o host?

Comment: valeu pela ajuda, então, o comando `netstat -l` me resulta isso ![imagem](http://www.tickimg.com.br/uploads/_netstat.png). Não vi referencia a porta 443.... mas como é um webserver liberado apenas pro ip de produção mesmo dentro do servidor prod. ubuntu usando o ping ele não encontra o host e só da falha. O problema é a  porta 443 mesmo?? O site utiliza `https://` e openssl-1.0

Comment: Na imagem, a porta 443 esta aberta (ele listou o protocolo ao invés do nome da porta, por ser uma porta conhecida), porém apenas com o bind no IPv6, e não no IPv4. Pode ser este o problema. No servidor de produção, o problema é mais complicado pois não conheço a topologia da sua rede. Recomendo que contacte com o administrador de rede.